# Recursive entry to executePendingTransaction

Tags: android, recursion, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

In brief i have such construction:

```
class AlbumPickerFragment extends PageFragment {

...

    @Override
    public void onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                              Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         mCallback.onViewCreated(this);
    }


}


public class PlaylistPickerActivity extends BaseActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        FragmentCreatedCallback callback = new FragmentCreatedCallback();
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            mFragments.add(PageFragment.newInstance(PageFragment.ALBUM_FRAGMENT_TYPE, callback));
            mAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), mFragments);
            mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        } else {
            restoring = true;
        }
    }


    Callback extends ICallback {

           public void onViewCreated(final Fragment fragment) {
                  mFragments.add(fragment);
                  mAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), mFragments);
                  mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
           }
    }
```

I got `illegal state exception`: recursive entry to executePendingTransaction. I know how to fix it, but i am just curious why does this happen. In my opinion it's something like this:

1. In activity's onCreate i created fragment and passed it to
   pager's adapter.
2. FragmentManager calls fragment's onCreateView
3. I called onViewCreated and passed my fragment to pager's adapter
           again AND i suppose there it goes to step 2 again.

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense. You have a a `ViewPager` with fragments, when the `ViewPager` builds those fragments in their `onCreateView()` method you call a callback which sets a new adapter on the same `ViewPager`, adapter which will contain the fragments that the `ViewPager` is already in the process of adding them. Also, please don't prefix your questions titles with Android, the tag at the bottom is more than enough.

Comment: I know, it's a bit of pseudo-code: that's what i got in the end, i mean Call Hierarchy. So am i right? FragmentManager->creates Fragment view->because of setting new adapter on the same ViewPager, FragmentManager trying to add this fragment again (and it is adding it right now, so we got recursion)

Comment: Something like that, you're trying to do a transaction with a fragment which is already involved in a transaction.

Comment: Many thanks! You really should make it an answer, so i can mark it as useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but i am just curious why does this happen.

You're not using the fragments properly. Right now you first build the `ViewPager` along with its adapter containing fragments. The problem is that in those fragments you have a callback which triggers a new adapter to be set on the `ViewPager` using the same fragments. As you already have a transaction in the process, trying to make another one in the process will not work.